# Azure sql server cannot create database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to create a database in Azure SQL server. However, when I try to create it, it prompts "Gen4 family is not available in this region" and cannot create the database. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

it has clearly mentioned that Gen4 family is not available in the region you have selected.

1. Your Region may only support gen5 hardware. choose gen5 or if you are using cli than provide
   `--family Gen5`

OR

2. Change the Region that have gen4 hardware.